# How to convert string Date to DateTime when you are selecting record through LINQ?

Tags: list, entity-framework, linq, date-conversion

I have a table that contains the entire history of the actions which are performed on the system by the users. I need to retrieve all those records in `date` `descending` order. The problem is I have saved the `date` in `string` format in my table, since my application support multi-culture. I don't know it was a good idea or bad, now I need to retrieve them in date `descending` order. So, when I am retrieving the data I am trying to convert the `date` to `DateTime` format, but I am getting an exception to `invalid date format`. In my database, the date is in `dd-MM-yyyy` format. Following is my query:

```
db.Histories.ToList.OrderByDescending(x=> Convert.ToDateTime(x.Date));
```

Comment: I would fix the database. Store dates as some sort of date (think `date` or `datetime`) representation in your database. That makes it formattable for any region, can deal with timezones, and sort correctly without any overhead of casting strings to dates and the all the troubles that come with it.

Comment: It is the best solution. However, is there any way to tackle this problem at this moment?

Comment: If you're getting 'invalid date format' from that, it's because .NET doesn't know how to parse the format of the date in the database. You may need to use `DateTime.ParseExact` to tell .NET how to deal with it.

Comment: Whenever i read _"In my database, the date is in XY-format"_ i could cry. Why don't you use `date` or `datetime` in your database?

Comment: Even with `ParseExact`, I would **highly** encourage you to implement sane date handling in your database ASAP. You'll probably spend more time doing hacks to support the string date then creating a separate datetime column in the table, creating a patch SQL script to migrate the data and drop the string column. That way it's done and you don't need to spend time hacking in date parsing.

Comment: The problem is my application supports multi-culture. How can I force to save the date in English format without converting it to string?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your data is not all of valid datetime format's.
You must cleen up the data first, I think. 
Or you could sort like this:

```
    var tmp = array.OrderByDescending(x => ParseDate(x.DateTest));


    private static DateTime ParseDate(string dateString)
    {
        var dateFormats = new[]
            {"dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy", "d.M.yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy"};
        try
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, dateFormats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return DateTime.Now.AddYears(-500);
        }
    }
```

Where the not valid datetime strings will end up last in the sorted list.